# Having doubt with interface

Tags: solidity, dapps, uniswap

I know that we don't inherit a contract from any interface, we first import it, then we do like this `ISomeInterface someInterface = ISomeInterface(address)`, but i saw this in uniswap document- `contract LiquidityExamples is IERC721Receiver {`. Please explain me.

Answer (score 0):

When a contract inherits from an interface, it needs to implement all the functions declared in that interface.
Example: `LiquidityExamples` is a contract and it uses `IERC721Receiver` interface.

This means `LiquidityExamples` must add code for the functions in `IERC721Receiver`. This helps `LiquidityExamples` work with `ERC721` tokens.

You can import without inheriting, by importing an interface you can use the interface inside your contract:

```
ISomeInterface someInterface = ISomeInterface(address)
```